# Dynamic colour change on scroll with jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a div which changes colour when I scroll down the page, from transparent to opaque. This code currently is using static RGB values and then adds an opacity value based on the scroll position.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        var $scrollPercent = ($(document).scrollTop() / windowHeight);

        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $(".fade-overlay").css({backgroundColor:'rgba(0,168,80,'+$scrollPercent+')'});
        } else {
            $(".fade-overlay").css({backgroundColor:'rgba(0,168,80,'+$scrollPercent+')'});
        }
    });
});
```

I want to change the static RGB values to dynamic ones.

At present I do have a hexadecimal colour value created by Advanced Custom Fields in a field called 'primary_colour'.
I can output this value as 'background-color' to a div but wonder if it is possible to convert this to RGB and insert it into the code I already have?

Can anyone possibly help me with my quandary about how to get this to work? I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: you would want to convert it with php [check this link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/convert-hex-to-rgb/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert the color format, just set your dynamic background color with the hexadecimal value (or whichever color value you have) and then set the opacity separately:

```
var primaryColour = "#00a850";

$(".fade-overlay").css({backgroundColor: primaryColour});
$(".fade-overlay").css({opacity: $scrollPercent});
```